# side-effects using declare(var,constant) in Maxima

Tags: maxima

In maxima, is the following behavior intended?

First example:

```
(%i1) declare(a,constant);
(%o1)                                done
(%i2) constantp(a);
(%o2)                                true
(%i3) square(a):=a^2;

define: in definition of square, found bad argument a
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
(%i4) load("linearalgebra.mac");

define: in definition of dotproduct, found bad argument a
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Second example:

```
(%i1) a:5;
(%o1)                                  5
(%i2) constantp(a);
(%o2)                                true
(%i3) square(a):=a^2;
                                              2
(%o3)                           square(a) := a
(%i4) square(a);
(%o4)                                 25
```

Third example:

```
(%i1) declare(a,scalar);
(%o1)                                done
(%i2) mat_f(a,b):=a.b - b.a;
(%o2)                    mat_f(a, b) := a . b - b . a
(%i4) mat_f(matrix([1,2],[3,4]),matrix([3,4],[1,2]));
                                [ - 10  - 14 ]
(%o4)                           [            ]
                                [  6     10  ]
```

It seems like `declare(a,constant)` has a global effect which to me seems strange in maxima. The second and third example work exactly how I would expect it.

Also are there any similar cases where something like this happens in maxima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maxima has a very weak notion of scope. Essentially all symbols are in the same scope, so when you make a declaration about `a`, it is about all instances of `a`, even the ones which are function arguments.

Maxima is actually a very old program and this is one of those aspects which has never been updated. There is discussion about giving Maxima a stronger notion of scope, but that will take some time.

Comment: So whenever I load a package like `linearalgebra.mac` I have to check its source code for the variables used in its function definitions? Or is it enough to just make sure to load it at the beginning of the program before making any declarations? I often use functions without explicitly loading the package so that is a bit inconvinient.

Comment: Probably the best course of action is to load the packages you need before making declarations. This is of course not really very satisfying, as it is only necessary because of Maxima's inability to distinguish symbols in different scopes.