# How to avoid the error thrown by the maxima function polynomialp?

Tags: constants, maxima, polynomials

Look at the following two sequences of two commands. They are the same up to the choice of variable a or z, but the version with a produces an error whereas the function with z does not.
First run (after a restart of maxima):

```
declare(a,constant); polynomialp(x^2+x+1/a,[x]);
```

Now replace a by z and there is no error when run (after a restart of maxima):

```
declare(z,constant); polynomialp(x^2+x+1/z,[x]);
```

The error reported in the case with variable a is:

```
define: in definition of dotproduct, found bad argument a
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Strangely enough, after running the second command of the first sequence again, the error does not recur.

Above code was run on Maxima versions 5.30 and 5.39.

Comment: This seems to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202981/side-effects-using-declarevar-constant-in-maxima

Comment: Thanks---the loading of linearalgebra.mac prior to the two commands works well.